# How to order a column in python without importing anything external?

Tags: python

I would like to know how I can order a column in excel through a file via python without importing anything externally?

Comment: Convert your "file" into a plaintext csv. Then load it up in python, and call sort with key. Refer to [Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)

Comment: If it's "in Excel" then impossible unless you wish to implement an Excel parser by hand.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with an excel file probably you will use pandas. I am not clear what you mean by "importing anything externally". But you can accomplish it using `pandas`. As an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
    'col2': [2, 1, 9, 8, 7, 4],
    'col3': [0, 1, 9, 4, 2, 3],
})

>>> df
  col1  col2  col3
0    A     2     0
1    A     1     1
2    B     9     9
3    D     8     4
4    E     7     2
5    F     4     3
```

You can sort df any column(s) as your wish.

Sort by col1

```
>>> df.sort_values(by=['col1'])
col1  col2  col3
0    A     2     0
1    A     1     1
2    B     9     9
3    D     8     4
4    E     7     2
5    F     4     3
```

Sort by multiple columns

```
>>> df.sort_values(by=['col1', 'col2'])
col1  col2  col3
1    A     1     1
0    A     2     0
2    B     9     9
3    D     8     4
4    E     7     2
5    F     4     3
```

If you finding another answer please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48982201/sorting-excel-column-with-python) question.

Comment: This is by definition using external libraries (something you have to download and install)